# Tools for inspecting .lib files?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm evaluating some underdocumented software. When I build a sample project, I'm getting a linker error that looks like:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
```

There aren't a whole lot of lib files with this app, so I can solve this problem with trial and error, but I know there's a more *elegant* way is to solve this problem.

In the java world, I would **grep FOO *.jar** to find the jar and I'm looking for the C++ analog. I'm working with C++ code in Visual Studio 2005.

I suspect the lib.exe utility with the /LIST option can get the information, but I've been unsuccessful so far. It just prints this:

```
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

granite50.dll
granite50.dll
granite50.dll
granite50.dll
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to See the Contents of Windows library (\*.lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

First of all you need to know which type of library you are looking at. Some libraries simply contain linkages for a DLL (i.e., import libraries) and others are code objects that become part of the executable image (i.e., static libraries). From the looks of that output, you were looking at a DLL import library.

Next you want to use the right tool. Lib.exe is used to extract object files from libraries and what-not. This is pretty much the same as the jar utility for Java. Microsoft provides dumpbin.exe which will dump information from the library. I see that [LarryF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488809/tools-for-inspecting-lib-files#488823) already mentioned this.

For import libraries, run `dumpbin.exe -headers foo.lib` and redirect it to an output file. The output will contain snippets for each symbol that the related DLL exports. Search for lines starting with `"  Symbol name  :"`. Note that there are two spaces before and after "Symbol name" if you want an exact match. You can also run the output through `findstr` to generate a list of symbols and redirect that to a text file if you want something a little nicer to look at:

```
dumpbin.exe -headers foo.lib | findstr /c:"  Symbol name  :" > foo-exports.txt
```

The other option is to open the related DLL with `depends.exe`.

Comment: For anyone having trouble running `dumpbin.exe` from `Powershell` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477387/cannot-find-dumpbin-exe/38616596#38616596

Comment: Was able to run this from the VS Command Prompt without issue.

Comment: Under windows11 tabbed command prompts this isn't in the default path for "command prompt" but it is for "developer powershell" and "developer command prompt"  I didn't have to do anything extra for these to show up with (visual studio 22)

Answer (score 16):

More than one thing can be your problem here.  I'm not sure looking in the lib file will be the best way to solve it, IMHO...  However, the DUMPBIN.exe is probably the tool you're looking for.  Use it from the command line, but make sure your paths are set, or use the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" that VS installs for you in your VS start menu.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to dumpbin. I did <b>dumpbin /all some.lib > some.dump</b> then grep'd through my dump files and found the library I needed to link.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a DLL and want to use it in your code with `__declspec(dllimport)` you can create the required LIB file easily if you have a DEF file for the DLL:

```
lib /def:mydll.def /nologo /machine:x86
```

which creates **mydll.lib**

This command should be run in the Visual Studio SDK Command Prompt.

A DEF file can be written manually extremely easy if you don't have one:
You open the DLL in **DependencyWalker** (http://www.dependencywalker.com), select "Save As" -> "Text with Import/Export lists" and have the **names** and **ordinals** of all exported functions in a txt file like this:

```
Export  Ordinal      Hint         Function                          Entry Point
------  -----------  -----------  --------------------------------  -----------
[C  ]    2 (0x0002)   1 (0x0001)  gsasl_base64_from                 0x000024F0
[C  ]    3 (0x0003)   2 (0x0002)  gsasl_base64_to                   0x000024A0
[C  ]    4 (0x0004)   3 (0x0003)  gsasl_callback                    0x000018B0
[C  ]    5 (0x0005)   4 (0x0004)  gsasl_callback_hook_get           0x00001900
[C  ]    6 (0x0006)   5 (0x0005)  gsasl_callback_hook_set           0x000018F0
[C  ]    7 (0x0007)   6 (0x0006)  gsasl_callback_set                0x000018A0
[C  ]    8 (0x0008)   7 (0x0007)  gsasl_check_version               0x00001870
[C  ]    9 (0x0009)   8 (0x0008)  gsasl_client_mechlist             0x00001E20
[C  ]   10 (0x000A)   9 (0x0009)  gsasl_client_start                0x00001F40
```

The rest is quickly done.
Create a **DEF file** which has this format:

```
EXPORTS
gsasl_base64_from @2
gsasl_base64_to @3
gsasl_callback @4
gsasl_callback_hook_get @5
gsasl_callback_hook_set @6
gsasl_callback_set @7
gsasl_check_version @8
gsasl_client_mechlist @9
gsasl_client_start @10
gsasl_client_suggest_mechanism @11
```

The number behind the @ is the ordinal.

---

P.D:
DependencyWalker can even **undecorate** cryptic names of C++ exports like

```
Foo@@YGHHH@Z   -->   int Foo(int, int).
```

Comment: Btw, this doesn't work anymore with x64 due to the ABI changes.

Answer (score 8):

this worked with a visual C++ express 9 .lib :

```
dumpbin.exe -headers clangParse.lib | findstr /c:"COMDAT"  > clangParse-exports.txt
```

or

```
dumpbin.exe -headers clangParse.lib | findstr /c:"sym="  > clangParse-exports.txt
```

thank you d.shawley

Answer (score 2):

open Visual Studio Command Prompt

dumpbin /all Effects11.lib > D:\1.txt