# Finding Reasons for Linking Errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries

I'm in the process of porting one of my project to an existing framework I've been developing. As a result I have two project, one that's the original I developed and then the ported one.

The problem I'm having is that the new project doesn't link. The error is *"... unresolved external symbol ..."* where the symbols should be defined in a library that's linked together with the project. By using VS command line tool **dumpbin.exe** I confirmed that the symbols said to be missing are in the library. The original project works fine, only by removing the library from the *Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies* do I get the same errors for that project.

Are there other reasons for *"... unresolved external symbol ..."* or am I simply not linking the library?

**Details**

The library in question is *OpenCL.lib* and the errors are *"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _clBuildProgram@24 referenced in function ..."* for all OpenCL API calls. Using the technique described in [Tools for inspecting .lib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488809/tools-for-inspecting-lib-files) I get the symbols for each function as one would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out. The library I'm linking with is only for x64 architectures, switching to that platform got it working.

Would've liked a more descriptive error from VS but what can you do...

Comment: It is recommended to change Visual Studio verbosity when issues happen during build, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329.aspx, as in that way you can read more information and probably can identify the cause more easily.