# "dumpbin" is not recognized. "dumpbin.exe" is missing

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, clr, dumpbin

**Screen witn issue (developer command prompt)**

[image: 1. Screen with issue (developer command prompt)]

> Problem description in English:
>   'Dumpbin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

**"Everything" can't find "dumpbin.exe"**

[image: 2. "Everything" can't find "dumpbin.exe"]

I use VS 2015 Community. I have repaired VS Installation, but problem is actual.

I will be grateful if you will help me with this issue.
P.S.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Did you add the location of `dumpbin.exe` to your PATH environment variable? (and then close and reopen `cmd.exe`?)

Comment: @Rob, I can't find `dumpbin.exe`. I searched with Everything programm. This file is missing

Comment: Can you please take a look in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin` (or similar/changing versions?). Also, can you try to run `Visual C++ 2005 Command Prompt` and run `dumpbin.exe` in there?

Comment: @Rob, I use VS2015. [Screen](http://imgur.com/g8yV2fI)

Comment: I just had a look, I don't have the file either. I [found this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) which mentions it cannot be run from the command line. However, I *did* find a copy of it under my SqlServer installation, if that's any help

Comment: @Rob, `You can start this tool only from the Visual Studio command prompt. You cannot start it from a system command prompt or from File Explorer.`. I tried use it from VS command prompt.

Comment: @Rob, I solved my problem. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I just checked that items.

[image: Check my screen]

Comment: Thorough explanation could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38616596/3095779